# Set property value

Tags: javascript

I have a user control. I set a property for that user control like:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
    get { return _selectedValue; }
    set { _selectedValue = value; }
}
```

I need to assign a value to property with "SelectedValue" using Javascript. How can I do that?

Comment: Add more code if you want to get an answer

Comment: What is this? It looks like C#, but you can't set a value in C# from Javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C#, and assuming you have access to some object that has the property `SelectedValue`, you can do that like this:

```
var value = "<%# YourObject.SelectedValue%>";
```

or, if you are working with Razor and MVC:

```
var value = "@YourObject.SelectedValue";
```

If you want to send this to server side code, you need to do as Zaheer Ahmed said, ajax or save the value in a cookie.

But there are so many assumptions, maybe you can post some more code and give some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a C# property from a client-side (js). You may use ajax to do some work, but you simply can't manipulate server-side code.

If you want to know the longer explanation, see how asp.net actually works, it's lifecycle etc. Simple way of putting it would be like this:

A user sends a request to the server using his browser. The server receives it, creates a requested page and instantiates needed classes etc. Then it's gets parsed and sent to the client as html (and other resources of course, like images, css...). The instantiated page class CAN'T be accessed and modified afterwards by the client, because it's already flushed by the server. Every request creates a new instance. There's no way of modifying c# with js anyway but its vice versa is possible. Can you imagine what it would be like, if you could use some js to modify C# on a remote server? users can hack your side by changing properties.